# Calculating number of entries in pandas dataframe below 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, lambda, apply

I have a pandas dataframe with many columns of which some are numerical and other categorical.

I want to calculate the number of negative entries in the pandas dataframe.  One way is to find which columns are numeric, subset these columns and then use simple syntax to calculate number of entries with negative values, e.g. `(df < 0).sum()`

Instead I tried a syntax with apply and lambda function which includes a conditional but I get a message that my syntax is erroneous.  Could you please explain to me why and how this idea could be implemented?

```
data.apply(lambda x: (if (x.dtype == 'int16' or x.dtype == 'float16'): (x<0).sum())).sum()
  File "<ipython-input-75-f329bf4e8cdd>", line 1
    data.apply(lambda x: (if (x.dtype == 'int16' or x.dtype == 'float16'): (x<0).sum())).sum()
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *ternary operator* here:

```
data.apply(lambda x: (x < 0).sum() if (x.dtype in ('int16', 'float16')) else 0).sum()
```

We thus return `0` (the neutral element of the (ℕ, +, 0) monoid) for non-numerical values.

Note that there are more numerical types than just `int16` and `float16`, you might want to use `np.issubdtype(..., np.number)` here:

```
import numpy as np

data.apply(lambda x: (x < 0).sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else 0).sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, a simpler solution is:

- use `select_dtypes` to get a subset of columns of numeric type,
- then use a *Numpy* `count_nonzero` function.

As this function counts non-zero values, we have to convert out DataFrame
into an array of *boolean* values, where *True* values are counted as non-zero.

So to sum up, the whole code can be:

```
np.count_nonzero(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number) < 0)
```